# Wireguard isn't working, 'wg0' doesn't exist

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, wireguard, ufw

I've got an issue with wireguard. I have a debian-based VPS, and a Manjaro client.
Here is my `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` of a server:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 194
PrivateKey = <ServerPrivateKey>
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = <ClientPublicKey>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
```

Here is my `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` of a client:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.2/32
PrivateKey = <ClientPrivateKey>

[Peer]
PublicKey = <ServerPublicKey>
Endpoint = <ServerIP>:194
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
```

Here is my `ufw status` output:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
143                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
993                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
51820                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
IMAPS                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
POP3                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
SMTP                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
194                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
143 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
993 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
51820 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
IMAPS (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
POP3 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
SMTP (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
194 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Here is my `lsmod | grep wireguard` output:

```
wireguard              94208  0
curve25519_x86_64      36864  1 wireguard
libchacha20poly1305    16384  1 wireguard
ip6_udp_tunnel         16384  1 wireguard
udp_tunnel             20480  1 wireguard
libcurve25519_generic    49152  2 curve25519_x86_64,wireguard
```

After `wg-quick up wg0` and `wg-quick down wg0` on a server I've got this error:
`` wg-quick: `wg0' is not a WireGuard interface ``
I'm sure, the mistake was on my side. But where was I mistaken?

Comment: Try using `wg` directly (instead of `wg-quick`) to set up a tunnel. Also keep in mind that `wg-quick down` will issue this message for any non-existent interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by writing different `PostUp` and `PostDown` commands, by changing an interface from `eth0` to `ens3` and also by changing port to a default wireguard one (194 was used by another service).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I simply had to rename my config file to something shorter. The error message is less than useful, eg:

```
# wg-quick up my-cool-vpn-name
wg-quick: `my-cool-vpn-name` does not exist

# mv my-cool-vpn-name.conf cool.conf
# wg-quick up cool
... all ok
```

I assume the length limit is inherited from Linux and some device-name length limit.